# Can't connect to SQL Server alias from local app

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a SQL Server instance named `OldServer\Instance` and one named `NewServer`. I need to send all of the apps that are currently referencing `OldServer\Instance` to use the new one instead.

I'm testing this concept by adding an alias on my local machine on `NewServer` of "OldServer" and creating an application that reads and makes updates to a table.

I have created the alias (TCP, port 1433) and tested that I can connect to it with a [Data Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e38h511e.aspx) successfully. When I made my Windows Forms app to connect to it, **it still connects to `OldServer\Instance`**.

Is there something I'm missing in IIS? Is it not possible to alias with an instance? Here is my connection string:

```
<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="server=OldServer\Instance;database=MyDB;UID=MyUser;Pwd=1234;"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"  />
```

Comment: Where did you create the alias in your DNS Server? If you ping oldserver which IP appears IP of oldServer or NewServer?

Comment: @MarcCals When I ping NewServer, it's fine. When I ping OldServer I get "cannot find host"

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dbrowne/archive/2012/05/21/how-to-add-a-hostname-alias-for-a-sql-server-instance.aspx.  You need to create a DNS record, among other things.

Comment: Where did you create the alias? Why don't you change directly the connection string to new Server?

Comment: @MarcCals I'm using SQL Server Client Network Utility. I can't change the connection string because my boss doesn't want to update 80 applications.

Comment: @TonyHinkle I'm not testing this on a webserver, but my local (Win8) machine. I tried adding it to the hosts file but no dice.

Comment: I don't know about other readers, but it's not clear to me what you've done--is "ailas" referring to a DNS alias or a SQL Server Native Client Configuration alias?  If you are testing this on a workstation, it isn't clear why you can't just change the connection string on the workstation--it's not clear why that would update 80 applications (unless they are running on your workstation).  I would suggest that you go through the config you have set up more thoroughly and rewrite the question so it is 100% clear exactly what you've done.  Not trying to be overly critical--just trying to help.

Comment: @TonyHinkle Thanks for your help. I'm doing this to prove a concept before we roll it out. The problem is that about 80 applications are referencing OldServer and we are moving all of that data to a new server called NewServer. I want to give the alias to NewServer as OldServer so that all of those applications will continue to work when OldServer is decommissioned. The task is to prevent us from having to go in and change the connections strings on all of those applications.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to clean DNS cache on the machine you are testing.

```
Click Start.
Enter cmd in the Start menu search text box.
Right-click Command Prompt and select Run as Administrator.
Run the following command: ipconfig /flushdns.
```

and run your code again

BTW, OldServer on of Off?

Comment: Both sql servers are on, I'm testing to see if the alias will overide the server name. It doesn't look like it's working, but only in my app.